# Redirect for /Static Not Working - Flask

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I don't want visitors to my FlaskApp to be able to see the contents of my Static folder.

At the moment when a visitor goes to myflaskapp.com/static, they are able to navigate and access my entire static directory.

I've tried using the following to redirect with no luck:

```
@app.route("/static")
@login_required
def staticroute():
    return redirect('/login')
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Was missing "Options -Indexes" from FlaskApp.conf file.

```
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```